Swift TensorFlowLite model inference is bad on device but fine in jupyter notebook -- how do I fix this?
I am trying to incorporate a TensorFlowLite video classification model (trained in a jupyter notebook) into an iOS project, but I'm encountering an issue where model inference is extremely bad when testing on the device despite it being quite good when run in a jupyter notebook.
The model is not giving me random guesses; it's actually just outputting extremely incorrect predictions with high confidence values.
I initially thought that perhaps there was an issue with how I pre-processed the frame data. However, after observing frame data before and after pre-processing, it looks to be accurate, albeit the processed input data is low resolution and cropped (however, I think this is the case in the notebook as well).
The whole processing chain for the app works like this:

Capture frames from the device camera (as CMSampleBuffer)
Resize and remove the alpha channel from the captured frame
After 48 frames have been collected, remove every other frame (this is because my model takes in 24 frames, and the python code has a frame step of 2.
Inference on the 24 frames collected; this step is extremely hacky because there is no way to directly store all of the outputs of the inference from the interpreter, so I have to manually pattern match each output to the corresponding input. I apologize if this is poorly explained, but I am essentially iterating through all outputs and feeding them back into the interpreter as inputs (excluding the input for the frame data and the output that contains the logits from inference)
After inferencing all frames, I perform softmax on the final logits output to get class predictions. The class predictions are consistently wildly incorrect.

Does anyone have any advice as to how I can get this model to work properly in this iOS project?
